# TYPO3 Scheduler: The page is not configured! [type= 0][]

Tags: cron, scheduler, typo3

I have a problem with my scheduler in TYPO3 4.5.5. Every time a task is executed it fails with the following error message:

```
[scheduler]: Task failed to execute successfully. Class: tx_jobportal_apply, UID: 5. The page is not configured! [type= 0][]
```

There are 3 domains in my page tree, each having an own root template. The TypoScript Object Browser shows a setup with page.typeNum = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.
I made a file reference in the root template in which the PAGE object was configured, like this

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: fileadmin/typoscript/template-setup_main.ts">
```

After configuring the object directly in the setup of the template no more error messages appeared and now I am a lucky guy ;)

@Koopa: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I can comment on this, so I'll post it as an answer..

I'm guessing you are initiating the TSFE in the scheduler task. Did you specify a page-id, and if so, have you checked this page is under a specific root-page with a typoscript template that has a 'PAGE' configured?

Comment: yes, i am initiating the TSFE in my task. like this
`// TSFE
  $GLOBALS['TT'] = new t3lib_timeTrackNull;
  $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_fe', $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], 2, 0);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_pageSelect');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->init(TRUE);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine = 
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRootLine(7, '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();`

the page with id 7 is a root page with typoscript template.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Your extension jobportal sends an error, check manually the action You are trying to do with scheduler.

Comment: i have the same extension working on another site. when i run the task manually, everything works fine.